# How do I compare a formula field with a picklist in a Validation Rule?

Tags: validation, formula, picklist

I have a custom object with a formula text field on it pulling from the master object.  I have a picklist field and upon saving want to check that the picklist value chosen matches the formula text field (both sets of values are exactly the same) - with an error message to advise someone to amend their picklist value choice if they do not match...  I am struggling with the syntax - can someone help?

Comment: Are you getting a syntax error? Posting your current validation rule and any errors would help.

Answer (score 8):

I think this should do it for you:

```
TEXT(Picklist_Field__c) <> Formula_Field__c
```

Comment: Agree with Dan.   ISPICKVAL(Picklist_Field__c, Formula_Field__c) might be another way to roll !

Comment: ISPICKVAL won't work as it expects a text literal in the second argument. Fields won't work there.